# VS Registry editor (Default) entries

Tags: c#, registry, explorer

While making a subkey in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\Shell\Edit With Asys\Command`, I noticed that there is no `(Default)` key.  I created a new String Value called `(Default)`, and set the value to `[TARGETDIR]Asys.exe "%1"`.

However, this does not work as expected, as in Regedit, in the proper location, there are two keys:

`(Default)` = `(value not set)` and
`(Default)` = `C:\Program Files (x86)\...\Asys.exe "%1"`

How should I go about setting the `(Default)` value if it does not show up in the editor? Or should I be doing something else?

Comment: If I don't recall it wrong the default key is when you set no name to the value.

Comment: @Gusman I see. That fixed it, Thanks!